# ScrollArea in QT Issue?

Tags: qt

I have one form where i am applying ScrollArea but it is not getting applied properly ?
I want to place the four buttons in Scrollable Area and when buttons gets increased a scroll bar should appear there to scorll down vertically.

Currently when i am trying to add more buttons the buttons overlap with the combobox and does not grow downward.

Here is my code :

```
 QPushButton *b1 = new QPushButton(strsearch);
           QPushButton *b2 = new QPushButton(strsearch);
           QPushButton *b3 = new QPushButton(strsearch);
           QPushButton *b4 = new QPushButton(strsearch);

 b1->setStyleSheet(

               "background-image: url(:/user.gif);"
               "background-repeat:no-repeat;"
               "background-attachment:fixed;"
               "background-position:left top;"
               "border-style: outset;"
               "background-color : black;"
               "border-width: 2px;"
               "border-radius: 10px;"
               "border-color: black;"
               "font: bold 16px;"
               "color: black;"
               "min-width: 10em;"
               "min-height: 0.75em;"
               "margin: 0 1px 0 1px;"
               "color:rgb(255,255,255);"
               "padding: 6px;"
               );



b2->setIcon(QIcon(":/user.gif"));
           b2->setIconSize(QSize(160, 26));
           b3->setIcon(QIcon(":/user.gif"));
           b3->setIconSize(QSize(160, 26));
           b4->setIcon(QIcon(":/user.gif"));
           b4->setIconSize(QSize(160, 26));

 QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
 layout->addWidget(b1, 1, 0);
           layout->addWidget(b2, 2, 0);
            layout->addWidget(b3, 3, 0);
            layout->addWidget(b4, 4, 0);
layout->addWidget(scrollArea);
  layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);
  setLayout(layout);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//Create the buttons
QPushButton *b1 = new QPushButton("Button 1");
QPushButton *b2 = new QPushButton("Button 2");
QPushButton *b3 = new QPushButton("Button 3");
QPushButton *b4 = new QPushButton("Button 4");

//Add the buttons to a vertical layout (faster than grid layout)
QVBoxLayout *scrollLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
scrollLayout->addWidget(b1);
scrollLayout->addWidget(b2);
scrollLayout->addWidget(b3);
scrollLayout->addWidget(b4);

//Create a viewport widget that contains the layout with buttons
QWidget *viewport = new QWidget;
viewport->setLayout(scrollLayout);

//Add the viewport to the scroll area
QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
scrollArea->setWidget(viewport);

//Add the scroll area to your main window's layout
mainLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);
```

Comment: @Riccardo : But I want to apply Scroll only to Buttons Area they are placed in QVBoxLayout according to your code.What is the need to apply mainLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);. Can I make it like this scrollLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);

Comment: @Riccardo : how to check in this if controls are added to main layout dont add it again ?

Comment: In a layout as in every other QObject you can use `children()` to get a list of all child objects, then search your object using the `contains()` method of QList.

Comment: `QObjectList list = layout->children();
 if(list.contains(myobject))
 {
 //code
 }`

Comment: @Riccardo : But QObjectList list = scrollLayout->children() contains every time 0 items ??

Comment: You are right that doesn't work. But back to previous question, I think you don't need to check if a widget is already in the layout. This situation is already handled by the `addWidget()` method that prevents to add a widget twice. To verify this try to copy `scrollLayout->addWidget(b1)` and paste it after button 4, so that you have this line twice, but running the program you'll see the button 1 only oce.

Comment: @Ric : You are correct. But my question is suppose i am doing the above functionality on a click of a button , for the first time when i press this button 4 buttons gets added to layout , now by mistake if user again press this button again 4 buttons are getting addedwhich i dont want...How to handle this situation ?

Comment: @Ric : In simple words if layout is added dont add it again.